# Async database API for Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, rdbms

Since working with databases requires input/output, may take unbounded amount of time, etc. it seems natural to want a non-blocking, asynchronous API. Is there one for Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard API like JBDC which would allow you to asynchronously call any DB. However there is [this  Google Project](http://code.google.com/p/adbcj/) which tries to do exactly this for PostgreSQL and MySQL.

You may also take a look at this question, which addresses similar stuff:

[Is asynchronous jdbc call possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4087696/947357)

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that such API exists but there are 2 different things: DB access libraries and a lot of ways to perform asynchronous calls in java.

- You can use either plain JDBC or any other higher level tool that simplifies DB access implementation to access your database.
- You can make asynchronous calls using JMS (if you are in Java EE environment) or using queues and executors from concurrency package if your are in JSE environment. Obviously a lot of other solutions available too.

Answer (score 1):

For [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/) I came across [Reactive Couchbase](http://reactivecouchbase.org/) which claims to do this and has a [Java Wrapper](http://reactivecouchbase.org/java.html). Didn't try it but there are several examples in the links.