# long running CallableStatement execute without wait

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have stored procedure which requires ~3 hours for execute. And i do not want wait until `procedure` return value or wait until CallableStatement `execute()` method was executed. Is there such a possibility in JDBC? Or i should use methods like trigger or execute in new thread? Thanks.

Comment: Nobody wants to wait, can you use threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was all set to reply but thought I'd check for dupes and found: [Is asynchronous jdbc call possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087696/is-asynchronous-jdbc-call-possible)

This answer gives lots of recommended patterns to workaround this "limitation". For me, I was all set to recommend you take a look at a threading solution, perhaps using [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) if you require mulitple IO-bound calls (although you'd need to be wary of clogging up db sessions).

Comment: Thanks, i will use triggers. Is more suitable for me. I do not want to control the threads.