# Configure Apache Cayenne to be used in an asynchronous manner with Vertx

Tags: java, postgresql, kotlin, vert.x, apache-cayenne

I'm using Apache Cayenne with Vertx. Vertx relies on everything to be asynchronous and it actively looks for threads that block.

So performing something like...

```
List<Artist> artists = ObjectSelect.query(Artist.class).select(context);
```

...will result in Vertx complaining with the following:

```
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 4750 ms, time limit is 2000
```

Please note that there are in fact ways to get around this by wrapping the code in an `executeBlocking` function as follows:

```
// Turning synchronous code to async in Vertx
vertx.executeBlocking<Any>({ future ->
     List<Artist> artists = ObjectSelect.query(Artist.class).select(context)
     future.complete(artists)
}, { res ->
     // The result
})
```

However, it becomes a pain to keep wrapping my ORM functions like that.

I wonder if there's a flag or a switch to turn Cayenne asynchronous? Or, if there isn't such a flag, I wonder if there's a way to use the [Postgres Async Driver by Mauricio](https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async). I pick that specific async driver because Vertx [provides native support for it](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mysql-postgresql-client/java/).

Comment: This an Apache Cayenne question so just leaving this as a comment: why not package your db service as a worker verticle? You'd get rid of the blocked thread warning and could easily scale up/out by exposing this service other the eventbus.

Comment: That's a great suggestion. If I communicate via the event bus with the vertx cayenne verticle then I assume I would need to create an abstraction layer over the event bus to communicate with the ORM?

Comment: You could use [Vert.x Service Proxies](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-service-proxy/java/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is no magic switch to make Cayenne async. Cayenne internally relies heavily on JDBC, which in it's turn is synchronous (and probably will be forever, see good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7616094/8098129)).

Moreover dependency on JDBC makes it really hard to use non-jdbc drivers, so no luck here too.

So custom wrapper suitable for your environment seems your best (if not only) option.

Comment: There is some talk about an [async JDBC from Oracle](https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/7464zn/asynchronous_jdbc_api_in_the_works/) which is stated for release in JDK 10, so hopefully they get that working in time.